# How do i add listview for android auto

Tags: android, android-auto, android-automotive

Im trying to biuld a simple android auto application.

I found some samples for "hello world" project.. but thats it.
Cannot find anything for creating a listview (for contacts) or any other views..  Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is an example:

```
private val predictionRows: MutableList<Row> = mutableListOf()
    private val mIcon = IconCompat.createWithResource(
        getCarContext(),
        R.drawable.ic_cog
    )

    init {
        val firstRoute = SpannableString("   \u00b7 Shortest route")
        firstRoute.setSpan(DurationSpan.create(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(26)), 0, 1, 0)
        val secondRoute = SpannableString("   \u00b7 Less busy")
        secondRoute.setSpan(DurationSpan.create(TimeUnit.HOURS.toSeconds(24)), 0, 1, 0)
        val thirdRoute = SpannableString("   \u00b7 HOV friendly")
        thirdRoute.setSpan(DurationSpan.create(TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(867)), 0, 1, 0)

        predictionRows.add(Row.Builder()
            .setTitle(firstRoute)
            .addText("Via NE 8th Street")
            .addText("Another row")
            .setImage(CarIcon.Builder(mIcon).build())
            .build())
        predictionRows.add(Row.Builder().setTitle(secondRoute).addText("Via NE 1st Ave").build())
        predictionRows.add(Row.Builder().setTitle(thirdRoute).addText("Via NE 4th Street").build())

    }

    override fun onGetTemplate(): Template {
        val listBuilder = ItemList.Builder()
        listBuilder.setOnSelectedListener(this::onItemSelected)
            .setOnItemsVisibilityChangedListener(this::onItemVisibilityChanged)

        predictionRows.forEach {
            listBuilder.addItem(it)
        }

        return ListTemplate.Builder()
            .setSingleList(listBuilder.build())
            .setHeaderAction(Action.BACK)
            .setTitle("Predictions:")
            .build()
    }
```